# awx docker compose phase fails

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to install AWX as part of a docker container image following the guide [here](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/tools/docker-compose/README.md) but it fails in the `docker-compose` step like so:

```bash
docker-compose -f tools/docker-compose/_sources/docker-compose.yml  up  --remove-orphans
tools_postgres_1 is up-to-date
tools_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting tools_awx_1 ...
Starting tools_awx_1 ... error

ERROR: for tools_awx_1  Cannot start service awx_1: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint tools_awx_1 (5711eb4a73513b5bd3c27c990761000325f71ae48dbe1e6308d33bf07382415a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for awx_1  Cannot start service awx_1: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint tools_awx_1 (5711eb4a73513b5bd3c27c990761000325f71ae48dbe1e6308d33bf07382415a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
make: *** [Makefile:485: docker-compose] Error 1
```

When I scan for the user of port 8080 it shows this:

```bash
$ sudo netstat -pna | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      733/java
```

This most likely appears to be related to Jenkins since I recollect having installed Jenkins with all default options and I use this port to reach to the Jenkins UI.

So what should be the alternative here without removing Jenkins ***or*** changing the port number for the Jenkins daemon (is it a daemon that runs Jenkins btw?) How can I change the endpoint for this AWX docker image? I'm rather new to docker and AWX, not to mention the devops ecosystem in general so would appreciate a bit of context around your suggestions.

Comment: In that _docker-compose.yml_, I guess you have something like `- "8080:8080"  # unused but mapped for debugging`?

Comment: Yes I see this. I tried commenting this line from the yaml file however issuing a `sudo make docker-compose` resets this file back to the original. Perhaps this file is generated on the fly? So I commented out lines with 8080 from two jinja2 template files. The build seems to have progressed further. Awaiting completion to check if it'll complete successfully

Comment: From what I see, the template conditionally wraps all those ports mapping. But I would guess that switching that `control_plane_node_count` condition off would actually prevent you from accessing some of the AWX interfaces you do care about.